# Uninitialized variable in if statement xcode

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, floating-point, initialization

I am trying to work with if else statements and I keep getting an uninitialized variable warning.
Is there a way to keep uninitialized or so that it is not a constant and may stay a variable based on an input from the UI.

```
- (IBAction)Calculate{
    float h1 = ([hole1.text floatValue]);
    float h2 = ([hole2.text floatValue]);
    float h3 = ([hole3.text floatValue]);
    float h4 = ([hole4.text floatValue]);
    float h5 = ([hole5.text floatValue]);
    float smallestNumber; 
    {
        if (h1 < h2 && h1< h3 && h1 < h4 && h1< h5) {
            h1 = smallestNumber;

        }else if (h2 < h1 && h2 < h3 && h2 < h4 && h2 < h5)
        {
            h2 = smallestNumber;
        }else if (h3 < h1 && h3 < h2 && h3 < h4 && h3 < h5)
        {
            h3 = smallestNumber;
        }else if (h4 < h1 && h2 < h3 && h4 < h3 && h4 < h5)
        {
            h4 = smallestNumber;
        }else
        {
            h5 =smallestNumber;
        }

       NSLog(@"%f", smallestNumber);

      smallestHole.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", smallestNumber];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`smallestNumber` *is* uninitialized, because
all your assignments are the wrong way around. Instead of

```
h1 = smallestNumber;
```

you probably want

```
smallestNumber = h1;
```

etc.